# WYSIWYG to create annotated images

Tags: wysiwyg

I have a special needs situation. I need a tool to allow annotating images. So, the WYSIWYG would have an image. I could click on a spot in the image and create a select box. I can size this box to whatever dimension need. I can then add text that will be associated with the box that will show up on a tool tip when the image is viewed.

So basically, need to be able to select an area of the image and save the coordinates of the area position and size, along with accompanying    text.